# How are multiple origins/destinations supposed to be used in google distance matrix?

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

I'm wondering about origins and destinations in distance matrix being plural. According to the documentation you can use several locations as a starting and/or finishing point.

How can several locations be one point?

Looking at other posts it seems as this is a way to find or route between locations? So then the api chooses one of the origin locations as the optimal (shortest distance?) starting point and one of the destinations as the optimal finishing point?

Answer (score 0):

Further down in the documentation it is written that the response will return one row between each origin and destination.

It is written under responses and not under the documentation for origins/destinations which is the reason this question is relevant.